# Product of a family of sets,

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $\left \{ A_{i} \right \}_{i\in I}$ and $\left \{ B_{j} \right \}_{j\in J}$ be families of sets. prove the following.

$$\left(\prod_{i\in I} A_{i}\right)\cap\left(\prod_{j\in J} B_{j}\right)=\prod_{(i,j)\in I\times J}(A_{i} \cap B_{j}) $$

**Proof:** Let $f\in (\prod_{i\in I} A_{i})\cap(\prod_{j\in J} B_{j}) \Rightarrow f\in \prod_{i\in I} A_{i})\wedge f\in \prod_{j\in J} B_{j} \Rightarrow f:I\rightarrow \bigcup_{i \in I} A_{i}  \wedge f(i)\in A_{i},\forall i\in I,  \wedge f:J\rightarrow \bigcup_{j \in j} B_{j}  \wedge  f(j)\in B_{j},\forall j\in j $, but I don't know how to continue in my proof, If I will continue in the proof I would have to gets to this.

$f:I\times J\rightarrow \bigcup_{(i,j)\in I\times J}(A_{i}\cap B_{j})\wedge f(i,j)\in A_{i}\cap B_{j},\forall_{(i,j)\in I\times J} $

I thought to use as Lemma $\bigcup_{(i,j)\in I\times J}(A_{i}\cap B_{j})=(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_{i})\cup (\bigcup_{j\in J}B_{j})$, I thinks it's true,   I would like you tell e if his property is true.

This is a problem of a book set theory Charles pinter.

Comment: “Grammar”NaziAlert: If you have a chain of implications, you don’t start with “Let”. You are saying “Let $f$ be an element of `blah` implies `etc`”. That’s ungrammatical. Be sure you read your formulas out loud as written to see if what you are writing makes grammatic sense.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is both a map $I\to \bigcup A_i$ and a map $J\to \bigcup B_j$, we conclude that 
$I = \operatorname{dom}(f)=J$. Hence the intersection $\prod_{i\in I}A_i\cap \prod _{j\in J}B_j$ is empty unless $I=J$.
And if $I=J$, it is immediate that $f$ in the intersection is in fact a map with $f(i)\in A_i\cap B_i$ for all $i\in I$. In other words,
$$\Bigl(\prod_{i\in I}A_i\Bigr)\cap \Bigl(\prod _{j\in J}B_j\Bigr)=\begin{cases}
\emptyset&I\ne J\\\prod_{i\in I}(A_i\cap B_i)&I=J\end{cases}$$
In general, this is not the same as $\prod_{(i,j)\in I\times J}(A_i\cap B_j)$.